# Java split target path with \

Tags: java, string, split, directory

I want to control in which folder my file is.

I work with a certain folder structure:

1. Main folder
2. processing subfolder
3. processed subfolder

To write my unit tests I want to put the test folder in the target which gives following folder structures

> target\test-folder\

This is the main folder

> target\test-folder\processing\

This is the subfolder processing

> target\test-folder\processed

This is the subfolder processed

I want to print out in which folder a certain file is, what I wanted to do is the following:

```
String[] directories = PATH.split("\"");
System.out.println(directories[directories.length - 2]);
```

When I debug I see that my array directories only contain 1 item, with the whole path, so my split is probably wrong.

What should I put as `split` value?

Comment: Probably ought to be using the types `Path` or `File`.

Comment: I agree with @Raedwald. You should not do String manipulation but rather use the File object, figure out the parent, and so on so forth

Comment: Ok seems a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you are using backslash as an escape character instead of what you want. You should split with argument `"\\"`, HOWEVER I'd advise you to use `FileSystems.getDefault().getSeparator()` instead of backslash, so it might run on linux or any other system (perhaps even in some magic land where people use `^` as path separator). Unfortunately in Windows it returns `\` (which is escape character) so you have to quote it using `Pattern.quote(String)`

The code should look like this:

```
String[] directories = PATH.split(Pattern.quote(FileSystems.getDefault().getSeparator()));
```

Comment: This throws: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1
\

Comment: Edited my answer, please try again

Comment: and it works. Thanks for the effort, you deserve the credits!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of splitting strings you should use the built in classes, such as `Path`. Contrived example to access the individual elements of the path:

```
Path p = Paths.get("target/test-folder/processed");
for (Path element : p) System.out.println(element); //loop over all elements
System.out.println(p.getName(2)); //access a specific element
```

which outputs:

> target
>   test-folder
>   processed
>   processed

Comment: One little detail, this needs to be dynamical. So it needs to be used in every folder on the file system with the 2 subfolders. But thanks for the answer.